# Laravel npm watch task fails with 'cannot read property 'module' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I am using Laravel 5.6.34, Node 8.11.1 and NPM 6.0.0.

I need to compile my scss to css and have Laravel watch changes to my files, so that I don't have to compile manually every time. However, when I run `npm watch` or `npm watch-poll`, I get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`

It fails at the development and the watch scripts.

When I run `npm run dev`, it compiles my changes.

I tried to change the npm run script in the package.json file to this: `"node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"` but it still fails.

These are my scripts, they are the standard ones that come with Laravel:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

I'm not sure what else I can try to make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and run npm install, then try running npm run watch again

Comment: Thank you. I had update node and do a few more tweeks, but all is working now.

Comment: can you accept my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete node_modules folder and run npm install, then try running npm run watch again